# UWP Tab close confirmation for page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I'm trying to make a close confirmation content dialog for closing the current tab.

Expected behavior: the app should ask the user if they want to save, and after, close the tab

Actual behavior: the dialog isn't shown. Here is the code:

MainPage (the one inside the tab):

```
    public bool IsCloseRequestComplete = false;

    public async void RequestClose()
    {
        if (TXTFile != null) { try { RAS = await TXTFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite); } catch { } }
        var Value = GetText(REB);
        var SecValue = GetText(RTB);
        if (Value != SecValue)
        {
            //Remember the user to save the file
            ContentDialog ED2 = FileSaveDialog;
            ED2.PrimaryButtonClick += ED2_PrimaryButtonClick;
            ED2.SecondaryButtonClick += ED2_SecondaryButtonClick;
            ED2.CloseButtonClick += ED2_CloseButtonClick;
            try { await ED2.ShowAsync(); } catch { }
            void ED2_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog SenderSec, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs DialogEvArgs)
            {
                if (TXTFile != null)
                {
                    //Save and close in the background
                    RAS.Dispose();
                    SaveCloseBackground();
                }
                else SaveClose();
            }
            void ED2_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog SenderSec, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs DialogEvArgs)
            {
                //Close
                if (TXTFile != null) RAS.Dispose();
                IsCloseRequestComplete = true;
            }
            void ED2_CloseButtonClick(ContentDialog SenderSec, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs DialogEvArgs) { }
        }
        else if (Value == SecValue)
        {
            //If the file is saved, close the app
            if (TXTFile != null && RAS != null) { try { RAS.Dispose(); } catch { } }
            IsCloseRequestComplete = true;
        }
        return;
    }
```

(SaveClose, SaveCloseBackground, GetText are custom methods)

TabbedMainPage (the tabbed page aka host page):

```
    private void TabbedView_TabCloseRequested(TabView sender, TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        MainPage MP = new MainPage();
        MP.RequestClose();
        if (MP.IsCloseRequestComplete == true)
            TabbedView.TabItems.Remove(args.Tab);
        else { MP.RequestClose(); }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: Kind of, but I need to adapt it a bit to my app's structure. I will mark it as helpful when I finish testing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the `ContentDialog`  on the MainPage. You need to put it on the Page which hosts the TabView. Then show the `ContentDialog` in the **TabCloseRequested**.

I made a simple demo about this and please check the following code.

Xaml:

```
        <muxc:TabView x:Name="MyTabView" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick"
           TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested">
        <muxc:TabViewItem Header="new header">
        </muxc:TabViewItem>
    </muxc:TabView>
```

MainPage(hosts the TabView)

```
        public ContentDialog noWifiDialog { get; set; }
    public muxc.TabViewItem targetTab { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = "No wifi connection",
            Content = "Check connection and try again.",
            PrimaryButtonText="OK"
        };
        noWifiDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += NoWifiDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;
    }

    private void NoWifiDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        // do the work you want

        Debug.WriteLine("Remove");

        //remove the item
        MyTabView.TabItems.Remove(targetTab);

        // clear the target item
        targetTab = null;
    }

    // Remove the requested tab from the TabView
    private async void TabView_TabCloseRequested(muxc.TabView sender, muxc.TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        //record the target tab 
        targetTab= args.Tab;
        // show the contentDialog. The close event of the ContentDialog is handled
        await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
    }



    // Add a new Tab to the TabView
    private void TabView_AddTabButtonClick(muxc.TabView sender, object args)
    {
        var newTab = new muxc.TabViewItem();

        newTab.Header = "New Document";

        // The Content of a TabViewItem is often a frame which hosts a page.
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        newTab.Content = frame;
        frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));

        sender.TabItems.Add(newTab);
    }
```